# Upload to .NET web service iOS

Tags: ios, xml, web-services, wcf, get

I need to pass some data in order for the server to the save the info,in order to do this the parameters need to pass the parameters in XML nodes following a url http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/WCF/Service1.svc/XXX/Upload?sXML=

Here is an example of the XML node structure

```
<Send_info>
<Service_order> 
</Service_order> 
<Data_stream> 
<info> 
</info> 
</Data_stream> 
</Send_info>.
```

The return value would be a JSON string with  {"Uploaded":"TRUE"} or {"Uploaded":"FALSE"} respectively.

I have tried this method with no answer it just return nil.

```
-(void)Request:(NSData*)data{
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/WCF/Service1.svc/XXX/Upload?sXML="];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request                                                           delegate:self];
[connection start];
}
```

edit:you can find the answer in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple just use these blocks of code and substitute them with your own parameters

POST:

```
 -(void)webservicepost:(NSString *)poststring{

NSString *poststring = @"String in the format we need to upload";

NSURL *remoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL in which we'll upload"];  

NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:remoteURL];

[Request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];//Formats for the data

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[poststring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //Add content and coding

[Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //POST method

[Request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:nil error:nil];//Server response in data form

NSString *sdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//Server response in string form

}
```

GET:

```
-(void)get:(NSString *)myxmlstring{
NSString *escapedString = [myxmlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/WCF/Service1.svc/XXX/Upload?sXML=%@",escapedString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:nil error:nil];//Server response in data form

NSString *sdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//Server response in string form

 //FROM HERE YOU CAN USE THE RETRIEVED INFORMATION FROM THE URL

}
```